# React :Unable to get this.state.name inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm new to `react` js and I'm trying to get the `firebase` authentication in my react js app . What I'm trying to do is , if user is logged in , then it should return the authenticated user's name or email id in my return page . I have been trying to implement various options in the state , But I can't able to get it . 
Here is my code

```
class Signin extends React.Component {
    state = {
        email :'',
        password:'',
        name :'',
        authUser:'',
    }
    getDetails = (e) => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
          authUser
            ? this.setState({ authUser }) 
            : this.setState({ authUser: null });
        });
    }
    render() {
        const {
            user,
            signInWithGoogle,
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
            {
                user
                    ? (
                        <div>
                            <button className="btn blue lighten-2 z-depth-0" onClick={this.logOut}>Sign out</button>
                            <button className="btn dark lighten-4 z-depth-0" onClick={this.getDetails}>GetDetails</button>
                            <input type = "text" className="dark lighten-2 z-depth-0" >
                                {this.state.authUser ? this.state.authUser :this.state.name}
                            </input>
                        </div>
                    )
                    : (
                        <button className="btn blue lighten-2 z-depth-0" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
                    )
            }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const firebaseAppAuth = firebaseApp.auth();
const loginAuth = firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword;
const providers = {
    googleProvider: new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(),
};

export default withFirebaseAuth({
    providers,
    firebaseAppAuth,
    loginAuth,
})(Signin);
```

In this page,  I can able to login the user via `firebase`, But can't able to get `onAuthstateChanged` .
Am I missing something ? Or should I store any variables after login?

Comment: Have you set value of `name` anywhere?

Comment: I didn't set the value for it ., but however I have mentioned it in state .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authUser` field is set in the component state in this part of the code you shared:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
          authUser
            ? this.setState({ authUser }) 
            : this.setState({ authUser: null });
        });
```

But it's not necessary to do that.

The `withFirebaseAuth` higher order component bears the responsibility to authenticate a user, already [does that when it mounts](https://github.com/armand1m/react-with-firebase-auth/blob/v1.0.4/src/index.tsx#L58) and [forwards a `user` prop](https://github.com/armand1m/react-with-firebase-auth/blob/v1.0.4/src/index.tsx#L130) to the Component it wraps.

```
<input type = "text" className="dark lighten-2 z-depth-0" >
   {user && user.displayName}
</input>
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable help. Next thing s , I want to use the  `authUser` state in another component  which is mentioned in another file . Can I do it or should I need to do `onAuthStateChanged `in that file too?

Comment: wrap the component that needs authentication with the `withFirebaseAuth` HOC and use the `user` prop that is forwarded to the wrapped component